# Tensorflow: Multithread enqueue_op when using py_func

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, io, queue

So until recently, I was feeding my model with a FIFOQueue which is queued using a `py_func` variable. The reason for this odd choice is that I generate training data on the fly and I have no other choice than calling a python function to generate this data.

It all worked nicely but I found myself limited by the speed at which the data is generated. I've already optimised the data generation algorithm so I'm now looking to start several enqueue threads.

Problem is: I obtain very odd and random errors. Sometimes it can be a SegmentationFault, sometimes it works until nothing gets ever enqueued (I suspect a deadlock)...

Here is roughly what I do:

```
def generate_example():
    ...
example = tf.py_func(generate_example, inp=[], Tout=...)    
enqueue_op = queue.enqueue(example)
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op] * 4)
tf.train.add_queue_runner(qr)
```

Note that I've tried crazy variations of this code (defining several distinct `example` variables, leading to different `enqueue_ops`..., defining distinct `generate_example` functions...).

From my understanding, since Python does not handle multithreading very well, this is not likely to work. But huh, maybe you guys know a way around?

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to create a simple example reproducing the errors ?